# Passing variables set in middleware.js to a page in the 'app/' directory in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm currently upgrading my Next.js 12 website to Next.js 13 and the 'app/' directory. And I'm having issues outputting variables set in the `middleware.js` file within the 'app/' directory.

I'm working off this example of Vercel's geolocation service used to ascertain the user's location. The full code example (next.js 12) can be viewed at their example [repository](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-middleware/geolocation).

The `middleware.js` file looks like this:

```
  export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
      const { nextUrl: url, geo } = req
      const city = geo.city || 'San Francisco'
      url.searchParams.set('city', city)

      return NextResponse.rewrite(url)
  }
```

Then in the `pages/index.tsx` the details are outputted as such:

```
export const getServerSideProps = ({ query }) => ({
  props: query,
})

export default function Index({
  city,
  country,
}) {
  city = decodeURIComponent(city)
  return (
   <div>{city}</div>
  )
}
```

As I'm upgrading to a next.js 13 website using the `app/` directory, I can no longer use `getServerSideProps`. The only other optionIi can find is to use the router, something similar to this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function HomePage() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const city = router.query.city

  return <div>City: {city}</div>
}
```

However, as my site is now using `import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'`, I can't figure out how to get the url query info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default export of your [`page.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page) gets passed an object which contains a `searchParams` for query strings, like so:

```js
// app/page.js

export default function HomePage({ params, searchParams }) {
  return <main>{searchParams.city}</main>;
}
```

You can also use [`useSearchParams`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params) to get it in any client component, for example:

```js
// app/ClientComponent.js

'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const search = searchParams.get('search')
 
  // URL -> `/dashboard?search=my-project`
  // `search` -> 'my-project'
  return <>Search: {search}</>
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Youssouf, great response!